# I can't delete empty value of my String array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a String array likes

```
var arr=["1","2",""];
arr.filter(Boolean);
arr.filter(function(e){return e != ""});
```

And I used one of these methods but that empty string still here.
note: I'm using chrome.

Comment: Typo. `retunr` -> `return`

Comment: Also note that the `filter()` method returns a new array, it doesn't work on the existing one by reference. As such you need to use `arr = arr.filter(...`

Comment: sorry but i type return it still not working

Comment: No, i used one of them, still not working

Comment: your code should work, just need to save array in a variable .. see below answers

Comment: @SumitRidhal that's using PHP

Comment: This works absolutely fine, as you can see in the snippet in [@BhushanKawadkar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58429975/519413). If it's not working *for you* then there must be another underlying problem. Please check the console for errors, and post a more complete example of your code.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var arr=["1","2","", "3"];
//arr.filter(Boolean);
arr = arr.filter(function(num){return num!=""});
console.log(arr);
```

You have to assign it back to arr.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working, you just need to correct type `retunr` to `return` and save modified array to variable

```js
var arr=["1","2",""];
console.log(arr);
arr.filter(Boolean);
arr = arr.filter(function(e){return e != ""});
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: your code should work as per code snippet i have posted. Did you see any console error? can you reproduce this on code snippet or jsfiddle so that i can take a look at it

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo (as @RoryMcCrossan sad), so the code must be:

```
var arr=["1","2",""];
var newArr = arr.filter(element => element !== "");

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use arr.filter to filter a value. but if you are using IE then may be filter is not workng then you need to use pure javascript.

```
var arr=["1","2",""];
arr=arr.filter(function(o){ return o!=""});
console.log(arr);

output
(2) ["1", "2"]

var k=[];
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){ if(arr[i]!=""){k.push(arr[i])}}
console.log(k);
```